# jquery date and time picker doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I use the following script http://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/

I try to add this code into my `asp.net` application but when I add `runat` server  in my `textfield` it doesn't work. Can somebody tell why?

This is my `textbox` in visual studio:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="datetimepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

This is how i add my css and javascript

```
<!--Add DateTime css-->
<link href="../../styles/jquery-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-------->

<!--Add DateTime JavaScript-->
<script src="../../scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../scripts/jquery-datetimepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-------->

<script>
    $('#default_datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        formatTime: 'H:i',
        formatDate: 'd.m.Y',
        defaultDate: '8.12.1986', //Startup datum
        defaultTime: '10:00' //Startup time
    });
    $('#datetimepicker_mask').datetimepicker({
        mask: '9999/19/39 29:59'
    });
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ value: '2015/04/15 05:03', step: 10 });
   </script>
<!-------->
```

Comment: can you post how do you import the plugin?

Comment: Use this `$('#<%= datetimepicker.ClientID %>').datetimepicker();`
it shold be help to you.

Comment: This is how i add my css and javascript

Comment: you can use also asp textbox instead of `<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >`. use only one time datetimepicker function. remove `$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ value: '2015/04/15 05:03', step: 10 });` this function and try it.

Comment: you can use only date in `value:'12.03.2013'` don't select time in value.

Comment: When i add $('#<%= datetimepicker.ClientID %>').datetimepicker(); I get the following error:The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: don't change your javascript just add '<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >' instead of `<asp:TextBox ID="datetimepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>` and remove this line `$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ value: '2015/04/15 05:03', step: 10 });` from  javascript.

Comment: Ok when i do that nothing happend when i klick on my textfield:S

Comment: I cannot reach $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker(); datetimepicker. No idea why?:s

Comment: Now i have this textfield:
<asp:TextBox ID="datetimepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
This is my javascript
<script>
        $('#<%= datetimepicker.ClientID %>').datetimepicker();
    </script>
When i run it it says:
Server Error in '/' Application.
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: Can somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong?